# how to set custom withAutomaticReconnect for signalR 3.0 on my angular project

Tags: angular, signalr

I'm trying to customized SignalR to try to reconnect during 60 sec with 3 sec interval

based on the documentation it seems that withAutomaticReconnect accepts an object implementing the IRetryPolicy interface, which has a single method named nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds.

this is where I need help and I don't know how to do that. (quite new in typescript)
I tried the below sample but get code error on elapsedMilliseconds:

*Property 'elapsedMilliseconds' does not exist on type 'number'*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reconnect-clients

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()    
.withAutomaticReconnect({
    nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: retryContext => {
        if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 60000) {               
            return 3000;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
})
.build();
```

any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what was going on with the OP because I was able to copy/paste their code as-is and it worked for me. Here is another example using a lambda function like the OP which sets policy that tries immediately, then again after 3 seconds, then after 10 seconds, then every 60 seconds forever.

```
const retryTimes = [0, 3000, 10000, 60000];

const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
  .withAutomaticReconnect({
    nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: context => {
      const index = context.previousRetryCount < retryTimes.length ? context.previousRetryCount : retryTimes.length - 1;
      return retryTimes[index];
    }
})
.build();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is of any help for you as your question is already 5 months old but since I just went through the pain of figuring this out writing this I just wanted to add this for future reference for anybody who needs this.

This is the object that implements `IRetryPolicy`:

```js
var OneMinuteReconnectPolicy = (function () {

    function OneMinuteReconnectPolicy() { }

    OneMinuteReconnectPolicy.prototype.nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds = function (retryContext) {
        return retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 60000 ? 3000 : null;
    };

    return OneMinuteReconnectPolicy;

}());
```

To use this you create an instance of it and pass that instance to `withAutomaticReconnect`, like:

```js
var reconnectPolicy = new OneMinuteReconnectPolicy();

connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withAutomaticReconnect(reconnectPolicy)
    .withUrl(chatHubUrl)
    .build();
```

If you want to see more details on what's going on you can add a line:

```js
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
```

just above the last line with `.build();` to get more detailed console logging.

In my testing I didn't get a retry every 3 seconds but about every 7 seconds. I think this is due to a 4 seconds timeout in the attempt to connect to the server. When this connect fails it then starts the 3 second delay of the reconnect policy.